# How do I change the image of a React Native bottom tab bar icon onTabPress?

Tags: react-native

I don't want the navigation to change, just the icon. So I can intercept the button press and prevent navigation, but I haven't been able to figure out how to change the icon. I want to change if from a Play to a Pause.

The nav option that displays the icon:

```
this.props={isPlaying:false}

const PlayStack = createStackNavigator({
  Play: PlayScreen,
});

PlayStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: ' ',
  tabBarIcon: () => (
    <PlayTabBarIcon
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (this.props.isPlaying ? 'ios-pause' : 'ios-play') : (this.props.isPlaying ? 'md-pause' : 'md-play') }
    />
  ),
  tabBarOnPress: (tab, jumpToIndex) => {
    this.props.isPlaying = !this.props.isPlaying;
    console.log(tab);
  }
};
```

And here's the `PlayTabBarIcon` class

```
import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'expo';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

export default class PlayTabBarIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Icon.Ionicons
        name={this.props.name}
        size={46}
        style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
        color={Colors.green}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Close. This one changes it `onPress` in the component: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606565/change-react-native-image-source-on-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this from the `tabBarOnPress` method of the `navigationOption`, but I did manage to get the functionality I needed inside the component. The component creation changes to:

```
const PlayStack = createStackNavigator({
  Play: PlayScreen,
});

PlayStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: ' ',
  tabBarIcon: () => (
    <PlayTabBarIcon
      playName={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-play' : 'md-play' }
      pauseName={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-pause' : 'md-pause' }
      isPlaying={false}
    />
  )
};
```

and the component changes to:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'expo';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

export default class PlayTabBarIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Icon.Ionicons
        name={this.state.isPlaying ? this.props.pauseName : this.props.playName}
        size={46}
        style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
        color={Colors.green}
        onPress={ () => this.setState({isPlaying: !this.state.isPlaying}) }
      />
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (this.state.isPlaying != prevState.isPlaying) {
      console.log('play state changed')
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isPlaying: props.isPlaying };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarIcon: ({focused }) => (    
    <Image resizeMode='cover' source={focused ? "Image URL Here": ""Image URL Here""} />
)
```

- focused parameter return Boolean value(This focused parameter check you are focused to the tab or not. if you're focused it's return true if you're not focused it's return false)